# format number 0.000 in android

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I'am trying to format my number from 1000000 into 1.000.000 and number such as 102 into 10,2 using this method :

```
public class NumberTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private DecimalFormat df;
    private DecimalFormat dfnd;
    private boolean hasFractionalPart;

    private EditText et;

    public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et)
    {
    df = new DecimalFormat("#.###,##");
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    this.et = et;
    hasFractionalPart = false;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        int inilen, endlen;
        inilen = et.getText().length();

        String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
        Number n = df.parse(v);
        int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
        if (hasFractionalPart) {
        et.setText(df.format(n));
        } else {
        et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }
        endlen = et.getText().length();
        int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
        if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
        et.setSelection(sel);
        } else {

        et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

    } catch (ParseException e) {

    }

    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
        {
        hasFractionalPart = true;
        } else {
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }
    }

}
```

but i got error, they said in logcat :

```
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: #.###,##
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277):    at java.text.DecimalFormat.initNative(DecimalFormat.java:567)
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277):    at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:560)
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277):    at java.text.DecimalFormat.<init>(DecimalFormat.java:538)
05-22 11:29:01.270: E/AndroidRuntime(27277):    at id.co.ajsmsig.espaj.method.NumberTextWatcher.<init>(NumberTextWatcher.java:23)
```

is there something wrong with my method? if yes, can you tell me where is my fault?

Comment: I think you have to use Locale to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving this exception because you are using the device with a Locale doesn't match the mask you are using.

Run this program to see what is the default mask on the current locale:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        String output = df.format(123456789.01);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Then apply the mask you want, using the locale that uses that mask. This is for Germany:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
        String output = df.format(123456789.01);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

The output is `123.456.789,01`

Complete details in here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

Comment: Can u tell me how to implement your code with format java for android?

Comment: It is the same. You also have Locale on Android. Just not the main method :)

Comment: but I don't know how to call locale in android for my decimal format :(

Comment: Locale current = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply, no it didn't help me :(